How to run ApexBatch with Client Credentials flow
I want to run an ApexBatch that exists in a Salesforce organization from a C# program.
[@RestResource(urlMapping='/BatchAction/*')

Apex specified is ready to go.
Also the connection application is configured.

Currently, I am unable to POST to get an access token from the C# program towards the Salesforce organization.
However, I was able to POST from Postman to get an access token.
The following is the configuration for that.
HEADERS
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
BODY
grant_type ： Client Credentials
client_id ：Secret key　
client_secret ：Consumer Key


Returns an error in tokenResponse. Status code 400 is displayed.
static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(Config config)
 {
     try
     {
         var requestBody = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
         {
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", config.ClientId),
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", config.ClientSecret),

         // new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "your_scope"),
     });

         var requestBodyContent = await requestBody.ReadAsStringAsync();
         Console.WriteLine($"Request Body: {requestBodyContent}");


         using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
         {
             var tokenResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(config.OAuthEndpointUrl, requestBody);
             Console.WriteLine($"Token Response Content: {tokenResponse.Content}");


             var tokenJson = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


             Console.WriteLine($"Request Body: {requestBodyContent}");


             Console.WriteLine($"Token Response Content: {tokenJson}");


The error output by C# is as follows
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:.
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-SFDC-REQUEST-CHECK: 2
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-ReadOnlyMode: false
  X-Robots-Tag: none
  Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0, private
  Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2024 22:30:25 GMT
  Set-Cookie: CookieConsentPolicy=0:1; path=/; expires=Thu, 24-Apr-2025 22:30:25 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; secure
  Set-Cookie: LSKey-c$CookieConsentPolicy=0:1; path=/; expires=Thu, 24-Apr-2025 22:30:25 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; secure
  Set-Cookie: BrowserId=Pw1m1gKKEe-QnEEnVTijnw; domain=.salesforce.com; path=/; expires=Thu, 24-Apr-2025 22:30:25 GMT; Max-Age=31536000
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
  Server: sfdcedge
  X-SFDC-Request-Id: 83670cef7a47bf8054e88aaef9a98115
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
}}

